# Custom csv export - customers

Tags: magento2, customer, csv, export, customer-csv

how can I add custom csv customer export and export only email and customer group? I need put this code to the own module.

Answer (score 1):

In default Magento 2 there is an option to export columns from grid view. You can enable only 2 columns - e-mail and customer group and hit export. 
[image]